# What is the opposing event for onerror

Tags: javascript, image, onerror

I have an image which is being updated by changing the `src` of the image with javascript. I added an `error` event listener to test if the image is broken and then reload the image if it is. But if it isn't broken, I want to remove the `error` event listener. Can't seem to figure out the right event that is an opposite to `onerror` while dealing with image.

```
<img src="path/to/img.jpg" id="img">

<script>
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var imgURL = "/path/to/new_img.png";
img.addEventListener('error', refresh);
img.src = imgURL;

function refresh(e) {
    img.src = imgURL;
    if(e.type !== "error") img.removeEventListener('error', refresh);
};
</script>
```

The last statement `e.type !== error` still falls within the error function and thus remains `false`. I need something i can call on if the event does not generate error. Somewhat like `onsuccess` if there's anything like that.

Comment: The `;` at the end of that function declaration is unnecessary. *Declarations* don't have `;` after them, just *(hand-waving away details)* statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite, for this specific case, is the `load` event indicating that the image loaded. I'm rather surprised to not find documented [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var imgURL = "/path/to/new_img.png";
img.addEventListener('error', refresh);
img.addEventListener('load', refresh); // ***
img.src = imgURL;
```

then

```
function refresh(e) {
    img.src = imgURL;
    if (e.type !== "error") {
        img.removeEventListener('error', refresh);
        img.removeEventListener('load', refresh);
    }
}
```

You might add some timeout and/or delay logic there, since otherwise this will constantly re-request the image until/unless it succeeds (which it may never do, if the URL is invalid).